# Set Discount Amount and Recalculae Tax

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a module in which admin can specify the date range and fixed shipping amount if any order is placed between the date range. Lets say calculated shipping is $100 and admin has specified that shipping amount should be $50, then difference between original shipping and specified shipping amount i.e $100 - $50 i.e $50 should be given as discount.

I have called an event sales_quote_collect_totals_after, where I am calling collectTotals function in my observer. In my observer I have calculated the discount amount and have set the discount amount on address.

But according to configuration settings, the total tax is applied on subtotal + shipping.

Lets say item total is $2000 and shipping total is $100, discount amount is $50, So grand total will be $2000 + $100 - $50 i.e $2050, and tax is about 20%. So tax amount should be $410, but calculated tax amount is appearing 20% of 2100 i.e $420 and grand total including tax is appearing $2050 + $420 i.e $2470 but It should be $2050 + $410 i.e $2460.

Can anyone please tell what I should do to recalculate Tax and Grand totals 
including tax ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of observing the `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event to make the changes you should instead register your own set of total models (address total, invoice total, creditmemo total) and configure them to be collected after `shipping` total and before the `tax` total.